# 'Figure' object has no attribute 'show'

Tags: python, network-programming, plotly, networkx

`Figure` object has no attribute `show`.

I am trying to visualizing a network using `plotly`. I have created the network by following `https://plot.ly/python/network-graphs/` but I am unable to see it in the workbook. Please help me.

```
Fig = go.Figure(data=[edge_trace, node_trace],
            layout=go.Layout(
                title='<br>Network graph made with Python',
                showlegend=False,
                hovermode='closest',
                margin=dict(b=20,l=5,r=5,t=40),
                annotations=[ dict(
                text="Python code: <a href='https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/network-graphs/'> https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/network-graphs/</a>",
                showarrow=False,
                xref="paper", yref="paper",
                x=0.005, y=-0.002 ) ],
                xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False),
                yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False)))
Fig.show()
```

It should generate the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to upgrade to version 4.0.0 of `plotly`.